# How Parcelable view member of object?

Tags: java, android, object, view, parcelable

I have an object with a View member. So i want to pass an ArrayList of this object and i need to pass this View. I know how to implement Parcelable.

The code is something like this :

```
public class Variable implements Parcelable {
    public View mView;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(mView)
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Variable> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Variable>() {
    public Variable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Variable(in);
    }

    public Variable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Variable[size];
    }
};

private Variable(Parcel in) {
   mView= (View) in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

So I tried object method for the writeToParcel and Variable(Parcel in) methods but obviously it didn't work.

How I should do this ?

Comment: `View` object are not `Parcelable`. You can only save the state of the View in Parcelable.

Answer (score 3):

You should only implement `parcelable` for data objects and never for Views, the idea is to `parcel/unparcel` the data state to re-instantiate a given `View` with state.

You should also note that there is a hard set limit on the size of the buffer that a transaction can hold when you parcel your data and send it via Intent. So ideally avoid having large in-memory object being transferred via parcel (one bad example is lets say `Bitmaps`)

Also, implementing parcelable by hand is pretty tedious and could be error prone. I recommend using Studio's plugin or any good third party plugin for implementing `Parcelable`.

Hope it helps